# Edit HostPath files as a root user in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

In Kubernetes when I create a pod it gets deployed in a node.
What I want to do is that I want to update the files of the node where that pod is deployed and which require the root permissions.
I mount the *HostPath* where I want to edit the files in my *pod yaml*.
Also, I have a docker image which has a script, this script wants to update the node filesystem lets say /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern. I have created a ServiceAccount and added it to privileged Security Context Constraints.

When I create the pod I get the error saying "Read-only file system".

Can someone tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to do either of these things?  Generally your containerization system isolates containers from each other and the host so that (by design) this sort of thing is difficult-to-impossible.

Comment: I know it is not a regular way to use the container but I have a requirement for which I need to edit the files of the hostpath. If it is difficult that is fine with me but not sure if it is impossible